# Trying to create chat functionality in my android studio project using Firebase database, " Cannot resolve sender id in my item view type" appears

Tags: javascript, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

Everything works fine but android studio don't seem recognize my Message Model class

Below is the message adapter class and the it throws error on senderId
How to do it right so as message model class can return all fields successfully?

```
public class MessagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Message> messages;
    final int ITEM_SENT = 1;
    final int ITEM_RECEIVE = 2;

    public MessagesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Message> messages){
        this.context = context;
        this.messages = messages;

    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType == ITEM_SENT) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_sent, parent, false);
            return new SentViewHolder(view);
        } else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_receive, parent, false);
            return new ReceiverViewHolder(view);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Message message = messages.get(position);
        if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid().equals(message.getSenderId())) {
            return ITEM_SENT;
        } else {
            return ITEM_RECEIVE;
        }

        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Message message = messages.get(position);
        if (holder.getClass() == SentViewHolder.class){
            SentViewHolder viewHolder = (SentViewHolder)holder;
            viewHolder.binding.feeling.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else {
            ReceiverViewHolder viewHolder = (ReceiverViewHolder)holder;
            viewHolder.binding.feeling.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }

    public class SentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ItemSentBinding binding;
        public SentViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            binding = ItemSentBinding.bind(itemView);

        }
    }
    public class ReceiverViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ItemReceiveBinding binding;

        public ReceiverViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            binding = ItemReceiveBinding.bind(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the Messages which seems to only return getMessage not recognising the rest

```
public class Message {

    private String messageId, message, senderId, imageUrl;
    private long timestamp;
    private int feeling;

    public Message() {
    }

    public Message(String message, String senderId, long timestamp) {
        this.message = message;
        this.senderId = senderId;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getMessageId() {
        return messageId;
    }

    public void setMessageId(String messageId) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getSenderId() {
        return senderId;
    }

    public void setSenderId(String senderId) {
        this.senderId = senderId;
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public int getFeeling() {
        return feeling;
    }

    public void setFeeling(int feeling) {
        this.feeling = feeling;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You say "it throws error on senderId". What is the exact error that you get?

Comment: #Alex Mammo thank you alot for the response but i resolved the error. The problem was to do with my Model class Constructor so i recreated it a fresh and the error was resolved